php development doesnt render my XML code in blade
we're developing a 2fa from google in our php laravel app but we encounter some problems. on localhost it works but on development it doesnt render the QR code at al.
What we've done until now is
<div class="w-full mx-auto grid justify-center">
     {{-- variation 1 --}}
     <?php  echo $image_url; ?>

     {{-- variation 2 --}}
     {!!$image_url!!}
</div>

on the controller:
    $image_url = $this->google2FA->getQRCodeInline(
        'test',
        Auth::user()->email,
        $secret
    );
    return view('auth.2fa-setup', compact(['image_url']));

output on development:

output of the $image_url:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200"><rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="#fefefe"/><g transform="scale(4.082)"><g transform="translate(4.000,4.000)"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10 0L10 1L8 1L8 2L9 2L9 3L8 3L8 4L9 4L9 3L10 3L10 2L12 2L12 3L11 3L11 4L10 4L10 5L8 5L8 7L9 7L9 6L10 6L10 7L11 7L11 13L12 13L12 14L13 14L13 15L12 15L12 17L11 17L11 15L7 15L7 14L6 14L6 13L9 13L9 12L10 12L10 11L9 11L9 10L8 10L8 9L10 9L10 8L6 8L6 9L7 9L7 10L5 10L5 8L0 8L0 10L1 10L1 9L4 9L4 12L5 12L5 13L3 13L3 12L1 12L1 13L0 13L0 14L1 14L1 15L0 15L0 17L1 17L1 16L2 16L2 14L6 14L6 15L7 15L7 16L6 16L6 17L4 17L4 18L3 18L3 17L2 17L2 19L0 19L0 21L1 21L1 20L2 20L2 19L4 19L4 20L3 20L3 21L2 21L2 22L3 22L3 23L4 23L4 22L5 22L5 24L4 24L4 26L3 26L3 25L2 25L2 23L1 23L1 22L0 22L0 23L1 23L1 25L0 25L0 26L1 26L1 25L2 25L2 28L3 28L3 29L2 29L2 30L3 30L3 31L2 31L2 33L3 33L3 32L4 32L4 30L5 30L5 29L7 29L7 28L8 28L8 29L9 29L9 30L6 30L6 31L9 31L9 32L8 32L8 35L9 35L9 36L8 36L8 41L9 41L9 40L10 40L10 39L11 39L11 41L13 41L13 40L12 40L12 39L14 39L14 41L15 41L15 39L14 39L14 38L17 38L17 37L16 37L16 36L17 36L17 35L14 35L14 36L15 36L15 37L14 37L14 38L11 38L11 34L10 34L10 33L11 33L11 32L10 32L10 31L11 31L11 30L10 30L10 29L11 29L11 28L10 28L10 27L9 27L9 26L10 26L10 25L12 25L12 26L13 26L13 28L14 28L14 29L15 29L15 30L14 30L14 31L12 31L12 32L14 32L14 31L15 31L15 33L14 33L14 34L16 34L16 31L17 31L17 32L19 32L19 31L17 31L17 30L16 30L16 29L17 29L17 28L21 28L21 30L24 30L24 31L22 31L22 33L21 33L21 32L20 32L20 34L25 34L25 36L24 36L24 35L19 35L19 34L18 34L18 35L19 35L19 36L18 36L18 37L19 37L19 36L24 36L24 37L21 37L21 38L20 38L20 39L19 39L19 40L20 40L20 41L21 41L21 40L24 40L24 41L25 41L25 39L26 39L26 40L27 40L27 41L29 41L29 39L30 39L30 41L32 41L32 40L33 40L33 41L37 41L37 40L38 40L38 39L40 39L40 40L41 40L41 39L40 39L40 38L38 38L38 35L39 35L39 36L41 36L41 34L38 34L38 32L39 32L39 33L41 33L41 31L39 31L39 30L40 30L40 29L39 29L39 30L37 30L37 29L38 29L38 28L37 28L37 27L33 27L33 26L34 26L34 25L33 25L33 26L32 26L32 27L31 27L31 28L29 28L29 27L28 27L28 26L29 26L29 25L30 25L30 26L31 26L31 24L33 24L33 22L32 22L32 21L31 21L31 22L29 22L29 21L28 21L28 20L30 20L30 19L31 19L31 20L32 20L32 18L33 18L33 16L34 16L34 18L35 18L35 19L33 19L33 21L34 21L34 20L35 20L35 21L36 21L36 22L35 22L35 23L34 23L34 24L36 24L36 25L37 25L37 26L38 26L38 27L40 27L40 28L41 28L41 27L40 27L40 26L41 26L41 25L40 25L40 26L38 26L38 25L39 25L39 24L41 24L41 21L39 21L39 22L38 22L38 21L36 21L36 20L37 20L37 19L40 19L40 20L41 20L41 19L40 19L40 18L41 18L41 17L40 17L40 18L38 18L38 15L39 15L39 16L41 16L41 13L40 13L40 15L39 15L39 14L38 14L38 13L37 13L37 12L38 12L38 11L39 11L39 10L38 10L38 8L37 8L37 11L36 11L36 13L33 13L33 12L35 12L35 11L34 11L34 10L36 10L36 8L35 8L35 9L34 9L34 8L33 8L33 4L32 4L32 7L31 7L31 6L30 6L30 5L31 5L31 3L33 3L33 2L30 2L30 1L29 1L29 2L28 2L28 3L24 3L24 2L23 2L23 1L22 1L22 0L20 0L20 2L19 2L19 0L18 0L18 2L19 2L19 3L18 3L18 4L19 4L19 3L21 3L21 4L20 4L20 5L17 5L17 4L16 4L16 3L17 3L17 2L16 2L16 0L14 0L14 1L15 1L15 2L14 2L14 3L15 3L15 4L14 4L14 7L13 7L13 5L12 5L12 4L13 4L13 2L12 2L12 1L13 1L13 0L12 0L12 1L11 1L11 0ZM26 0L26 1L25 1L25 2L27 2L27 0ZM32 0L32 1L33 1L33 0ZM21 1L21 3L22 3L22 4L24 4L24 3L23 3L23 2L22 2L22 1ZM29 3L29 4L28 4L28 5L27 5L27 7L26 7L26 6L25 6L25 5L26 5L26 4L25 4L25 5L20 5L20 6L19 6L19 7L18 7L18 6L17 6L17 5L15 5L15 8L14 8L14 10L15 10L15 11L14 11L14 12L12 12L12 13L13 13L13 14L14 14L14 15L13 15L13 16L14 16L14 17L12 17L12 18L11 18L11 17L10 17L10 16L8 16L8 17L6 17L6 18L7 18L7 19L6 19L6 20L8 20L8 21L5 21L5 22L8 22L8 24L7 24L7 23L6 23L6 24L7 24L7 25L5 25L5 27L4 27L4 29L5 29L5 27L6 27L6 28L7 28L7 27L6 27L6 26L7 26L7 25L8 25L8 26L9 26L9 25L10 25L10 22L14 22L14 23L12 23L12 25L13 25L13 24L14 24L14 23L15 23L15 25L14 25L14 26L15 26L15 27L14 27L14 28L15 28L15 27L17 27L17 26L15 26L15 25L18 25L18 27L21 27L21 28L22 28L22 27L23 27L23 25L24 25L24 26L26 26L26 24L29 24L29 22L28 22L28 21L26 21L26 19L24 19L24 20L23 20L23 19L22 19L22 18L23 18L23 17L24 17L24 18L27 18L27 16L28 16L28 17L29 17L29 18L30 18L30 17L32 17L32 16L31 16L31 14L32 14L32 15L33 15L33 13L32 13L32 12L28 12L28 11L29 11L29 10L30 10L30 11L32 11L32 9L33 9L33 10L34 10L34 9L33 9L33 8L31 8L31 7L30 7L30 6L29 6L29 5L30 5L30 3ZM10 5L10 6L11 6L11 7L12 7L12 6L11 6L11 5ZM16 6L16 10L17 10L17 11L15 11L15 12L14 12L14 13L15 13L15 15L14 15L14 16L15 16L15 17L14 17L14 18L16 18L16 19L14 19L14 20L15 20L15 21L14 21L14 22L17 22L17 21L16 21L16 20L17 20L17 18L16 18L16 17L18 17L18 19L19 19L19 20L18 20L18 21L19 21L19 20L21 20L21 21L20 21L20 22L19 22L19 24L18 24L18 23L16 23L16 24L18 24L18 25L19 25L19 26L20 26L20 25L21 25L21 26L22 26L22 25L23 25L23 24L24 24L24 23L23 23L23 22L22 22L22 21L23 21L23 20L22 20L22 19L21 19L21 18L22 18L22 17L23 17L23 16L24 16L24 15L26 15L26 16L25 16L25 17L26 17L26 16L27 16L27 15L28 15L28 16L29 16L29 15L30 15L30 14L29 14L29 13L28 13L28 12L27 12L27 13L26 13L26 14L24 14L24 15L23 15L23 12L24 12L24 11L23 11L23 10L22 10L22 9L23 9L23 8L24 8L24 9L25 9L25 8L24 8L24 7L25 7L25 6L24 6L24 7L23 7L23 6L22 6L22 7L23 7L23 8L22 8L22 9L21 9L21 6L20 6L20 7L19 7L19 9L20 9L20 10L22 10L22 11L23 11L23 12L22 12L22 13L21 13L21 11L18 11L18 9L17 9L17 8L18 8L18 7L17 7L17 6ZM28 6L28 8L26 8L26 10L25 10L25 12L26 12L26 11L28 11L28 9L31 9L31 8L29 8L29 6ZM12 8L12 11L13 11L13 8ZM39 8L39 9L40 9L40 8ZM2 10L2 11L3 11L3 10ZM5 11L5 12L8 12L8 11ZM40 11L40 12L41 12L41 11ZM17 12L17 13L16 13L16 14L17 14L17 15L16 15L16 16L18 16L18 15L19 15L19 17L20 17L20 18L19 18L19 19L20 19L20 18L21 18L21 17L22 17L22 16L23 16L23 15L22 15L22 14L21 14L21 13L20 13L20 12ZM1 13L1 14L2 14L2 13ZM18 13L18 14L19 14L19 13ZM20 14L20 15L21 15L21 14ZM28 14L28 15L29 15L29 14ZM34 14L34 15L35 15L35 14ZM36 14L36 15L38 15L38 14ZM3 15L3 16L5 16L5 15ZM35 16L35 18L36 18L36 19L35 19L35 20L36 20L36 19L37 19L37 16ZM9 17L9 18L8 18L8 20L9 20L9 21L8 21L8 22L10 22L10 20L12 20L12 21L13 21L13 18L12 18L12 19L11 19L11 18L10 18L10 17ZM4 18L4 19L5 19L5 18ZM9 18L9 19L10 19L10 18ZM27 19L27 20L28 20L28 19ZM24 20L24 22L25 22L25 23L26 23L26 22L25 22L25 20ZM3 21L3 22L4 22L4 21ZM20 22L20 23L21 23L21 24L23 24L23 23L22 23L22 22ZM27 22L27 23L28 23L28 22ZM31 22L31 23L30 23L30 24L31 24L31 23L32 23L32 22ZM36 22L36 23L37 23L37 25L38 25L38 24L39 24L39 23L40 23L40 22L39 22L39 23L37 23L37 22ZM0 27L0 33L1 33L1 27ZM24 27L24 28L23 28L23 29L24 29L24 30L26 30L26 31L25 31L25 34L26 34L26 35L27 35L27 36L28 36L28 35L27 35L27 34L29 34L29 35L32 35L32 32L31 32L31 33L29 33L29 32L30 32L30 31L31 31L31 29L32 29L32 28L31 28L31 29L28 29L28 30L30 30L30 31L27 31L27 30L26 30L26 29L27 29L27 28L28 28L28 27L27 27L27 28L26 28L26 27ZM9 28L9 29L10 29L10 28ZM24 28L24 29L26 29L26 28ZM33 28L33 29L34 29L34 30L32 30L32 31L37 31L37 30L35 30L35 29L34 29L34 28ZM12 29L12 30L13 30L13 29ZM18 29L18 30L19 30L19 29ZM26 31L26 33L28 33L28 32L27 32L27 31ZM5 32L5 33L7 33L7 32ZM9 32L9 33L10 33L10 32ZM23 32L23 33L24 33L24 32ZM33 33L33 36L36 36L36 33ZM9 34L9 35L10 35L10 34ZM34 34L34 35L35 35L35 34ZM12 36L12 37L13 37L13 36ZM25 36L25 37L24 37L24 38L23 38L23 39L25 39L25 38L26 38L26 39L27 39L27 38L26 38L26 36ZM29 36L29 37L28 37L28 39L29 39L29 38L30 38L30 39L31 39L31 38L30 38L30 36ZM31 36L31 37L32 37L32 36ZM33 37L33 38L32 38L32 39L33 39L33 40L35 40L35 39L34 39L34 37ZM35 37L35 38L36 38L36 37ZM9 38L9 39L10 39L10 38ZM21 38L21 39L20 39L20 40L21 40L21 39L22 39L22 38ZM16 39L16 41L18 41L18 40L17 40L17 39ZM36 39L36 40L37 40L37 39ZM0 0L0 7L7 7L7 0ZM1 1L1 6L6 6L6 1ZM2 2L2 5L5 5L5 2ZM41 0L34 0L34 7L41 7ZM40 1L35 1L35 6L40 6ZM39 2L36 2L36 5L39 5ZM0 41L7 41L7 34L0 34ZM1 40L6 40L6 35L1 35ZM2 39L5 39L5 36L2 36Z" fill="#000000"/></g></g></svg>

